# Error in building boost library for Android framework on Linux

Tags: linux, boost, android-ndk, boost-thread, boost-regex

I am facing a problem while building boost library from [latest version 1.53.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/latest/download?source=files).

While following all steps as described in most of the tutorials for building boost library on Linux system for Android NDK, a weird error is occurring:

> ./boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:269: error: no matching
> function for call to 'hash_value(const wchar_t&)'

This error is encountering while building code files for *regex*, *thread*, *wave* and *graph* only, other then this all were successfully compiled.

Here is the user settings made in *user-config.jam* file

```
import os ; 

if [ os.name ] = CYGWIN || [ os.name ] = NT 
{ 
        androidPlatform = windows ; 
} 
else if [ os.name ] = LINUX 
{ 
        androidPlatform = linux-x86_64 ; 
} 
else if [ os.name ] = MACOSX 
{ 
        androidPlatform = darwin-x86 ; 
} 

androidNDKRoot = ../android-ndk-r8e ; 
using gcc : android4.4.3 : $(androidNDKRoot)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/$(androidPlatform)/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ : 
    <compileflags>--sysroot=$(androidNDKRoot)/platforms/android-9/arch-arm 
    <compileflags>-mthumb 
    <compileflags>-Os 
    <compileflags>-fno-strict-aliasing 
    <compileflags>-O2 
    <compileflags>-DNDEBUG 
    <compileflags>-g 
    <compileflags>-lstdc++ 
    <compileflags>-I$(androidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include
    <compileflags>-I$(androidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include 
    <compileflags>-I$(androidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi/include 
    <compileflags>-D__GLIBC__ 
    <compileflags>-DBOOST_NO_INTRINSIC_WCHAR_T 
    <archiver>$(androidNDKRoot)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/$(androidPlatform)/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar 
    <ranlib>$(androidNDKRoot)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/$(androidPlatform)/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib ;

modules.poke : NO_BZIP2 : 1 ;
```

using android-ndk-r8e version and command line to generate archived code files:

> ./b2 --with-**regex** toolset=gcc-android4.4.3 link=static runtime-link=static target-os=linux --stagedir=android
>
> ./b2 --with-**thread** toolset=gcc-android4.4.3 link=static runtime-link=static target-os=linux --stagedir=android
>
> ./b2 --with-**graph** toolset=gcc-android4.4.3 link=static runtime-link=static target-os=linux --stagedir=android

couldn't get what is missing?

> EDIT: Igor R please find the error stack for thread code file generation:

```
In file included from ./boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:529,
                 from ./boost/functional/hash.hpp:6,
                 from ./boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:37,
                 from ./boost/thread/thread.hpp:22,
                 from libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:12:
./boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp: In member function 'size_t boost::hash<T>::operator()(const T&) const [with T = wchar_t]':
./boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:249:   instantiated from 'void boost::hash_combine(size_t&, const T&) [with T = wchar_t]'
./boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:263:   instantiated from 'size_t boost::hash_range(It, It) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const wchar_t*, std::basic_string<wchar_t> >]'
./boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:322:   instantiated from 'size_t boost::hash_value(const std::basic_string<Ch, std::char_traits<_CharT>, A>&) [with Ch = wchar_t, A = std::allocator<wchar_t>]'
./boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:434:   instantiated from here
./boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:269: error: no matching function for call to 'hash_value(const wchar_t&)'
./boost/system/error_code.hpp: At global scope:
./boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: warning: 'boost::system::posix_category' defined but not used
./boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: warning: 'boost::system::errno_ecat' defined but not used
./boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: warning: 'boost::system::native_ecat' defined but not used

    "/home/username/android/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pedantic --sysroot=/home/username/android/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -mthumb -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -lstdc++ -I/home/username/android/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include -I/home/username/android/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include -I/home/username/android/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi/include -D__GLIBC__ -DBOOST_NO_INTRINSIC_WCHAR_T -pthread -Wextra -Wno-long-long -pedantic -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_BUILD_LIB=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_DONT_USE_CHRONO -DBOOST_THREAD_POSIX -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/thread/build/gcc-android4.4.3/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/pthread/thread.o" "libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/thread/build/gcc-android4.4.3/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/pthread/thread.o...
```

> Answer: Thanks to Igor R, after adding -DBOOST_NO_STD_WSTRING option in *user-config.jam* resolved the building issue.

Comment: It seems that these libs do not honor BOOST_NO_INTRINSIC_WCHAR_T macro. However, the previous version of Boost.Thread used to compile well, so maybe it's a regression - could you post the error stack for Boost.Thread?

Comment: Igor I have added the error stack in post itself.

Comment: I see. Try defining also -DBOOST_NO_STD_WSTRING

Comment: Thanks much Igor.. it worked...
Please can you tell where can i look for the significance of all these options.

Comment: You can find out the meaning of every config macro in Boost.Config docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__03_defects